# Can I connect via REST services with a mobile app I will develop?

Tags: 8, commerce, services

I'm thinking of developing an e-commerce with Drupal 8 and Drupal Commerce, but I need to know if I can connect via REST services with a mobile app that I would develop too. The app would need to be able to create carts, make orders, payments, and so on.

I have already developed several apps which connect to Drupal 8 and created content, but I need to know if it's possible to create orders, carts, payments, etc.

Comment: Google's first hit for 'drupal 8 commerce rest cart': https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_api. So the answer is: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: The linked project supports only cart operations.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can exposes entities and other resources as RESTful web API by activating the core RESTful Web Services module

> /admin/modules